# Using "Group" function for Million records in Excel

Tags: excel

I have an excel data dump of around 700k rows. Below is the structure of the data:
Member ID, Category of Item, Sub Category, Sales, Units.

Now I am looking to group all rows with same member ID and when I expand it I should see all the Categories/Sub Categories the member bought. I tried doing this using pivot, but this huge loads of data is crashing when I operate pivot table.

Can I achieve this using Group function in Excel? Generally I manually select rows and group them. But not sure how can I use group function over 700k rows.

Thanks,

Comment: Pivot table seems like the right option for me. Even if you can group like you request (I have no clue whether you can or not), it seems like that would take just as long.

Comment: Thanks Kyle. Are there any other tools that are good at handling million records. Basically I am providing this data dump to some sales rep team who are gonna use this on a daily basis.  I am thinking of using Tableau for displaying the records. Any other alternative?

Comment: My recommendation was going to be Tableau, so you're on the right track. Really, any database with a basic Excel front end would probably work too.

Comment: Hey. I am able to achieve this with Tableau. Use of 'actions' helped me group data at whatever level I want.